# Step size in macro's do loop in sas

Tags: loops, sas, sas-macro

So I want to run nested loop for my macro function.
Here's my code, it seem like SAS doesn't like `by -1`. Is there anyway I code this to let the second loop decrease step by -1?
In this case, my `yearMix = 1982` and `yearMax = 1994`.

```
%Macro theLoop;
    %Do I = &yearMin+1 %to &YearMax-1;
        %Do J = &YearMax-1 %to &I by -1;
            %Meaw;
        %END;
    %END;
%MEND theLoop;
%theLoop;
```

I got this error:

> ERROR: A character operand was found in the %EVAL function or %IF condition where a numeric operand is required. The condition was: &I by -1
>   ERROR: The %TO value of the %DO J loop is invalid.
>   ERROR: The macro THELOOP will stop executing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You specify your increment in a macro `%do` loop using `%by` rather than `by`. Further details can be found in the user guide [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000543755.htm).

In your code SAS is trying to evaluate `&I by -1` as a numerical value.

Answer (score 0):

```
%let yearMin = 1982;
%let yearMax = 1994;

%Macro theLoop;
    %Do I = %eval(&yearMin+1) %to %eval(&YearMax-1);
        %Do J = %eval(&YearMax-1) %to &I %by -1;
            %put &i =  &j = ;
        %END;
    %END;
%MEND theLoop;
%theLoop;
```